# Issue with making synchronous call to google maps direction Api on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, synchronous, google-directions-api

I am trying to make a synchronous call to google maps Direction Api. But I get "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". My code is as below. If I use awaitIgnoreError() it returns null. In my Android gradle file compileSdkVersion is 29 and minSdkVersion is 23. Could someone please help to resolve  this?

```
 geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key))
                .build();

        DirectionsApiRequest request = DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext)
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(dest)
                .mode(mode)
                .alternatives(altroutes);

        try{
            DirectionsResult result = request.await();
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Time consuming operations are not allowed in the main thread as it might affect the performance of the app. You should execute request in background. Have a look at Android docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check.